# Sensor data live stream

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, http

I'm in a student organization that builds race cars (yes, actual formula cars!), and I somehow ended up being their web dev. Now I'm working on a way to display live data on the website, from sensors on the car (like temperature, acceleration, rpm etc.). It kind of works now, the setup for the "data stream" is as follows:

`Sensors > Telemetry > Computer in the pit > via GET to a php interface > MySQL Database > Frontend webpage using php and ajax (every second)`

I think this works pretty good all the way to the database, but I would like to have some sort of stream to the webpage, so that data is sent from server to client as the database is updated, instead of being requested by the client. The car sends about 4-5 packets (containing data from all of the sensors) every second.

So my question is: **Is there a way to achieve this, and if so, what are some efficient ways to go about doing this?**

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Also, good luck at Formula Student.

Comment: You can use ordinary AJAX ops - a race car is likely to have a dedicated web server, which will amply cope with one request per second. However, if you can use Web Sockets, that is considered better, since you can push updates to the client listener whenever they become available.

Comment: @jurgemaister I appreciate the feedback, I realized the question might have been a bit broad, but thought I'd give it a go to see if i could get some pointers. Thanks for the good luck!

Comment: @halfer We do not have a dedicated web server, though that would be great. Also, the current setup works all right, but I want *more* than one request per second, to have more of a real time feel to it. Thank you anyways, I am looking into websockets!

Comment: OK. In a real situation I imagine the web server would be in at the pitside garage, and signals would be broadcast using a local radio system. The web server would not need to be very powerful to achieve sub-second response times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into websockets! For example http://socketo.me/.

Comment: I had already looked into websockets, but was not sure whether it would be the right thing, and do not have a lot of time to research different solutions before my deadline. Looking a bit more into it now, it seems you are right. Thank you for the answer!